# Wiremock socket blocked IN_NATIVE

Tags: java, resttemplate, wiremock

I'm occasionally my tests get stuck hanging (this happens on our build servers and not locally).  Using jstack shows me that the tests are stuck while waiting for a socket read.  This could be down to using wire mock in my unit tests or rest template? Has anyone seen this before?

where my test looks like

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class XxxServiceTest {
    private static final int PORT = 10222;
    private static final String HOST = "localhost:" + PORT;
    private static final String PATH = "/1.0/api";
    private static final String ACCOUNTS_PATH = PATH + "/user";
    private static final String TWO_FACTOR_VALIDATE_PATH = "/validate/token";
    private static final String QUESTION_MARK_WITH_ANY_PARAMETERS = "?.*";
    private static final int HTTP_OK = 200;
    private static final int HTTP_NOT_FOUND = 404;
    private static final int HTTP_FORBIDDEN = 401;

    private static final String ENCRYPTED_USER_ID = "?userId=";
    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
    private static final String TWO_FACTOR_AUTH_CODE = "SOME_TwO_FACTOR_AUTH";

    @edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(value="URF_UNREAD_PUBLIC_OR_PROTECTED_FIELD", justification="JUnit rules must be public")
    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(PORT);

    private XxxService testSubject;

    @Before
    public void createTestSubject() throws Exception {
        final RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        testSubject = new XxxService(template, authorityGranter);
        final String http = "http://";
        set(XxxService.class, "restUrl").to(http + HOST + PATH).on(testSubject);
        set(XxxService.class, "authUrl").to(http + HOST + TWO_FACTOR_VALIDATE_PATH).on(testSubject);
    }

    private PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken tokenWithPrinciple(final String principle) {
        final AuthenticationDetails details = new AuthenticationDetails(Optional.of(principle), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(TWO_FACTOR_AUTH_CODE));
        return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(details, "");
    }

    private void respondsWithAccountDetails() throws IOException {
        responseWithContentsOfFile("/somefilepath/XxxServiceTest.response.json");
    }

    private void responseWithContentsOfFile(final String filename)  throws IOException {
        final String json = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename));
        stubFor(get(urlMatching(ACCOUNTS_PATH + QUESTION_MARK_WITH_ANY_PARAMETERS))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withStatus(HTTP_OK)
                        .withBody(json)));
    }

    private void failsTwoFactorAuth() {
        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(TWO_FACTOR_VALIDATE_PATH)).willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(HTTP_FORBIDDEN)));
    }

    @Test(expected = TwoFactorAuthenticationException.class)
    public void failsAuthenticationWhenTwoFactorCodeIsIncorrect()  throws Exception{
        // Given
        respondsWithAccountDetails();
        failsTwoFactorAuth();

        // When
        testSubject.loadUserDetails(tokenWithPrinciple("PrincipleTokenWithoutValidTwoFactor"));
    }
}
```

And the production code looks like:

```
public class XxxService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(UrsService.class);

    @Value("${services.user.restUrl}")
    private String restUrl;

    @Value("${services.user.authUrl}")
    private String authUrl;

    private final RestTemplate rest;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(final PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token) {
        final AuthenticationDetails principalToken = (AuthenticationDetails) token.getPrincipal();

        validateTwoFactorToken(principalToken.getTwoFactorAuthCode());

        try {
            return getUserDetails(principalToken);
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException|HttpClientErrorException e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Failed to fetch user details.", e);
        }
    }

    private void validateToken(final String twoFactorAuthCode) {
        validateTwoFactorToken(twoFactorAuthCode);
    }

    private void validateTwoFactorToken(final String twoFactorAuthCode) {
        try {
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + twoFactorAuthCode);
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("twoFactor", headers);
            final ResponseEntity<String> validation = rest.exchange(authUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException |HttpClientErrorException e) {
            throw new TwoFactorAuthenticationException(twoFactorAuthCode, e);
        }
    }

    private UserDetails getUserDetails(final AuthenticationDetails principalToken) {
        final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", restHeaders());
        final ResponseEntity<User[]> exchange = rest.exchange(restUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, User[].class, principalToken.getEncryptedUserId().get());
        return UserDetails.from(exchange.getBody(), authorityGranter);
    }
}
```

The full output from jstack is:

```
Attaching to process ID 11243, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.31-b07
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 11431: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run() @bci=421, line=626 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11430: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=7, line=404 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(java.net.Socket) @bci=60, line=545 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.ServerSocket.accept() @bci=48, line=513 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty6.DelayableSocketConnector.accept(int) @bci=8, line=34 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run() @bci=212, line=708 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run() @bci=42, line=582 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11372: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=142 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=158 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.java2d.Disposer.run() @bci=3, line=148 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11287: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(long, int, long, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(long) @bci=18, line=269 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(long) @bci=28, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(long) @bci=37, line=86 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(long) @bci=30, line=97 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select() @bci=2, line=101 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=43, line=154 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.fill(byte[], int, int) @bci=36, line=139 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(int) @bci=130, line=159 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readByte() @bci=6, line=255 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.readByte() @bci=8, line=80 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read() @bci=8, line=63 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read() @bci=5, line=52 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive() @bci=8, line=77 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionReceive.run() @bci=8, line=235 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=5, line=54 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run() @bci=33, line=40 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11286: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.queue.EndPointQueue.take(java.util.Collection) @bci=55, line=49 (Compiled frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionDispatch.run() @bci=37, line=278 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=5, line=54 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run() @bci=33, line=40 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11285: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=79, line=150 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=121 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=214, line=246 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(byte[], int, int) @bci=44, line=286 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=49, line=345 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(sun.net.www.MessageHeader, sun.net.ProgressSource, sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection) @bci=51, line=703 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(sun.net.www.MessageHeader, sun.net.ProgressSource, sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection) @bci=56, line=647 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0() @bci=327, line=1535 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() @bci=52, line=1440 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() @bci=16, line=480 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode() @bci=8, line=48 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode() @bci=5, line=33 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse) @bci=5, line=56 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse) @bci=7, line=50 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(java.net.URI, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod, org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse) @bci=14, line=629 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(java.net.URI, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod, org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback, org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor) @bci=75, line=597 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(java.lang.String, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod, org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback, org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=26, line=557 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(java.lang.String, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod, org.springframework.http.HttpEntity, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=31, line=475 (Interpreted frame)
 - xxx.xxx.XxxService.validateTwoFactorToken(java.lang.String) @bci=75, line=82 (Interpreted frame)
 - xxx.xxx.XxxService.validateToken(merlin.web.traderportal.app.security.AuthenticationDetails) @bci=63, line=72 (Interpreted frame)
 - xxx.xxx.XxxService.loadUserDetails(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken) @bci=14, line=54 (Interpreted frame)
 - xxx.xxx.XxxServiceTest.failsAuthenticationWhenTwoFactorCodeIsIncorrect() @bci=22, line=255 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=0 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=100, line=62 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=6, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=56, line=483 (Compiled frame)
 - org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall() @bci=19, line=47 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run() @bci=5, line=12 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=14, line=44 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate() @bci=16, line=17 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate() @bci=14, line=19 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate() @bci=61, line=26 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule$1.evaluate() @bci=38, line=62 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate() @bci=8, line=20 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(org.junit.runners.model.Statement, org.junit.runner.Description, org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier) @bci=28, line=271 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod, org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier) @bci=42, line=70 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(java.lang.Object, org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier) @bci=10, line=50 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run() @bci=16, line=238 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=5, line=63 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier) @bci=51, line=236 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(org.junit.runners.ParentRunner, org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier) @bci=6, line=53 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate() @bci=12, line=229 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier) @bci=31, line=309 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier) @bci=21, line=37 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier) @bci=9, line=62 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(java.lang.String) @bci=297, line=105 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(java.lang.String) @bci=22, line=56 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestClassRunInfo) @bci=30, line=64 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestClassRunInfo) @bci=9, line=50 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=0 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=100, line=62 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=6, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=56, line=483 (Compiled frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.MethodInvocation) @bci=23, line=35 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(java.lang.Object) @bci=9, line=24 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(java.lang.Object) @bci=30, line=32 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=246, line=93 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestClassRunInfo) @bci=20 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestClassRunInfo) @bci=22, line=106 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=0 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=100, line=62 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=6, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=56, line=483 (Compiled frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.MethodInvocation) @bci=23, line=35 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(java.lang.Object) @bci=9, line=24 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run() @bci=211, line=360 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=5, line=54 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run() @bci=33, line=40 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11265: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 11264: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=142 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=158 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=36, line=209 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11263: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=502 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=36, line=157 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11259: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt() @bci=1, line=836 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int) @bci=72, line=997 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(int) @bci=24, line=1304 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await() @bci=5, line=231 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(org.gradle.process.internal.WorkerProcessContext) @bci=70, line=69 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(java.lang.Object) @bci=9, line=45 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(org.gradle.process.internal.child.WorkerContext) @bci=110, line=85 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(java.lang.Object) @bci=9, line=37 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(org.gradle.process.internal.child.WorkerContext) @bci=219, line=87 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(java.lang.Object) @bci=9, line=41 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call() @bci=41, line=49 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call() @bci=5, line=33 (Interpreted frame)
 - jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.run() @bci=313, line=69 (Interpreted frame)
 - jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.main(java.lang.String[]) @bci=11, line=74 (Interpreted frame)
```

Comment: I've just got exactly the same issue again on exactly the same test.  I'm wondering if maybe this is due to there being no body content mocked for the validateTwoFactorToken rest call?

Comment: Also noticed this in jstack:

Comment: Have you tried a 2.x-beta version of WireMock?

This upgrades to Jetty 9 under the hood, so might solve your problem.